# Spring boot SSL with node JS

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, ssl

A nodeJS project should communicate with a Spring boot SSL project. On NodeJS side we have a .crt and .key files. FRom Spring boot project side, how to enable SSL using these two instead of using a keystore and a passphrase. Current configuration on spring boot side:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.pfx
server.ssl.key-store-password=pass
```

Node JS code:

```
new https.Agent({ 
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_PATH, 'utf8'),
      key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.KEY_PATH, 'utf8')
  })
});
```

Error:

error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate,
error: Error (stacktrace) >Error: unable to verify the first certificate,
 at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1048:34)